# SwiftUI variable not transferring to FullScreenCover

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been stuck on this problem for about a day now and I'm hoping that someone here is able to help me.

The "main" view is the 'AvailableCarsView' which contains a list of every car the user has access to. When the user wants to edit a car, he clicks on it from the list.

I'll walk through and show the relevant pieces of code of the 'AvailableCarsView' now:

I start with initialising the 'selectedCar' object I wish to send to the new view:

```
    // I init this car so it can be replaced by the selected car later.
@State var selectedCar: Car = Car(id: "-1", owner: User(), carName: "", carLicensePlate: "", active: false, drivers: [Driver]())
```

When that has been completed, (the list of available cars has already been prepared) I show them in a list like so:

```
    var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            // Loop through available cars
            ForEach(availableCars) { car in
                
                Button {
                    
                    // Set the selected car == to the car in the list.
                    self.selectedCar = car
                    
                    // Set the 'showEditCarView to true to show the fullscreenCover
                    self.editCarView = true
                    
                } label : {
                    HStack(spacing: 14) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            Spacer()
                                .frame(height: 5)
                                .clipped()
                            Text("\(car.carName)")
                                .font(Font.system(.headline, design: .default).weight(.medium))
                            Text("Owned By: \(car.owner.name)")
                                .font(Font.system(.subheadline, design: .default).weight(.regular))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                            Text("Click to edit")
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .padding(.top, 8)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.tertiaryLabel))
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    Divider()
                }
                Divider()
            }
            Divider()
            Button {
                // NEW CAR
                self.newCarView = true
            } label: {
                Text("+ Add new Car")
                    .font(Font.system(.subheadline, design: .default))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                Divider()
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .clipped()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .clipped()
            .padding(.top, 0)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $newCarView, content: {
            
            NewCarView(loggedInUser: loggedInUser, newCarView: $newCarView, availableCars: $availableCars)
        })
        
        // For some reason, 'selectedCar' is not being transferred to this view.
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $editCarView, content: {
            EditCarView(loggedInUser: self.loggedInUser, car: selectedCar)
        })
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on a car I set the `car` object equal to the `selectedCar` which has been initialised previously. (That is in the first button).

The first `.fullScreenCover` works perfectly. However, she 2nd one doesn't seem to properly transfer the `selectedCar`. It **does** transfer the `loggedInUser` perfectly.

The code for the `editCarView` looks as follows:

```
struct EditCarView: View {

let loggedInUser: User
var car: Car

@State var carName = ""

// I init this view because I need to extract the individual components of the car object to variables. But for some reason, it shows an empty car. (= the car I init in the previous view)
init(loggedInUser: User, car: Car){
    
    self.car = car
    self.loggedInUser = loggedInUser
    
    self.carName = car.carName
    
    print(car)
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            
            Form{
                
                Group{
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Car Name:")){
                        TextField("", text: $carName)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("\(car.carName)")
    }
}
```

}

Unfortunately this does not work and the result looks like this: (note that the .navigationTitle doesn't show either)

[image]

I have already tried the following things, which didn't work:

1: Make `selectedCar` a binding variable
2: Remove `Task{}`
3: Init a fullScreenCover in the button (doesn't work unfortunately)
4: Init it through a method
5: Creating a new car Object from the selectedCar object in the initialiser

I'm really stuck here and I wouldn't know what else to try. Perhaps it's a stupid mistake, it often is but I would greatly appreciate if someone would be able to help me out.

Thank you very much for your time and I wish you all a nice day :)

Comment: Use `fullScreenCover(item:` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem in the future:

@Asperi 's answer worked. You have to use `fullScreenCover(item:` instead :)